# inputenc error: problems reading in .bib file from jabref

Tags: bibtex, input-encodings, jabref

i'm relatively new to latex, so forgive me, if thats a silly one:
I'm using miktex and texstudio.
I keep getting the following error message, which prevent me from building up or compiling a document

"inputenc: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `latin1'. 0.67bifeo3â
inputenc: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding`latin1'. \newblock Développement par compression de l"

They first appeared, when i first cited a certain reference. I understand they are due to certain characters in the .bib file. So i changed the characters in the .bib file with jabref. That didn't work, then i deleted those citations from my document, didn't work either. Now i even started to build up a new .bib file, in which i type everything by hand. But even with that one and all citations removed, i keep getting this error message.
Anyone any ideas?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you delete the bbl-file and recalled bibtex/biber to create a new one?

Comment: i deleted it and that did the trick! thanks! but i can only recall a new one with bibtex. how can i do that with biber? do i adjust that in my texstudio configurations?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the default encoding used by JabRef. The easiest way to go is asking for `utf8` encoding and use `biber + biblatex` instead of `bibtex`. Biber understands utf8 and brings may new features, so you'll have no problem with accented letters.